# background-image no-repeat position: right not appearing. Image reference OK. What gives?

Tags: html, css

I have a really noob question but since I can't get it to work I need to ask anyway. This **exact** same code works on my other site. So why isn't this code displaying the separator to the right of the header?

http://jsfiddle.net/jay_t55/2g13bfz2/1/

```
<header>
    <h1>Assessment Site</h1>
    <h2>Welcome...</h2>
</header>

header
{    
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    padding-top: 30%;

    border-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/2jE2sDU.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
}

header > h1, h2
{
    font-size: 22pt;
    color: #131313;

    margin-left: 25%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code says 'border-image', change that to 'background-image'.

The background-position entry should have two arguments in it as well. Horizontal and vertical. I've added center as the vertical.

```
header
{    
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 30%;
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/2jE2sDU.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right center;
}
```

Comment: Here's a link to Chris Coyier's post on using border-image. You need some other rules as well as simply the image declaration. http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-image/